# Discord Bot [C#] Bot Responds to Commands but then Doesn't Continue?

Tags: c#, discord, dsharp+

[The bot in Discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4lLh.png)

As you can see, it responds to the request, but then doesn't do anything with the number I've entered. It just sits there.

Here is my code for that command (currently it's just copied from the DSharp tutorial website, I planned to modify it significantly, but it won't even do the standard):

```
        [Command("waitforcode"), Description("Waits for a response containing a generated code.")]
    public async Task WaitForCode(CommandContext ctx)
    {
        // first retrieve the interactivity module from the client
        var interactivity = ctx.Client.GetInteractivity();

        // generate a code
        var codebytes = new byte[8];
        using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
            rng.GetBytes(codebytes);

        var code = BitConverter.ToString(codebytes).ToLower().Replace("-", "");

        // announce the code
        await ctx.RespondAsync($"The first one to type the following code gets a reward: `{code}`");

        // wait for anyone who types it
        var msg = await interactivity.WaitForMessageAsync(xm => xm.Content.Contains(code), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        if (!msg.TimedOut)
        {
            // announce the winner
            await ctx.RespondAsync($"And the winner is: {msg.Result.Author.Mention}");
        }
        else
        {
            await ctx.RespondAsync("Nobody? Really?");
        }
    }
```

If anybody could help me, that would be great!

Comment: Have you debugged it? If you put a breakpoint in `xm.Content.Contains(code)`, you should see that getting called for each message, I think

Comment: So it hit the break point, interactivity was null and code was correctly set to the generated code. I then pressed continue and entered the code, and nothing.

Oh, just another note, it doesn't time out either. Or, rather, maybe it does, but it doesn't send the timeout message to the server.

Comment: "*interactivity was null" -- wait what? If that's the case, that line should have throw a `NullReferenceException`, which would cause it to return from that command immediately (which would explain it). If you're using Visual Studio, go to Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings, and make sure the checkbox next to "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" has a tick in it (if it's a solid block, keep clicking it until it gets a tick). Then try again.

Comment: Okay, that was disabled for some reason. It's now back on and it's throwing the exception every time it hits interactivity. Okay, this potentially gives me something to go on now, however I'm unsure how to proceed as I set interactivity to ctx.Client.GetInteractivity(); Do you think there's possibly something inside the GetInteractivity method that's been missed?

Comment: I don't know the Discord API I'm afraid -- you'd have to look at their docs to see why `CommnandContext.Client.GetInteractivity()` might return null.

Comment: Cool, will do! Thanks for the tip on VS debugging though, no idea why it was turned off and it would have taken me ages to think about whether it was or not.

Comment: There should have been a message in the output window about a first-chance exception, but it's easy to miss. There's a "Restore" button at the top of the "Exception Settings" window, on the right-hand end of the row of icons, which resets those checkboxes to their defaults (some aren't checked by default, and that's normally a good thing). They can become unchecked if an exception occurs, the little dialog pops up, and you tick/untick the option to hide that exception in the future (I don't recall what the exact message is)

Answer (score 0):

It means you haven't got **Interactivity** specified before requesting it,
use the **UseInteractivity** method before executing any commands, you need to only run it once, here's an example method use:

```
var interaction = client.UseInteractivity(new DSharpPlus.Interactivity.InteractivityConfiguration()
    {
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
        
    });
```

You need to have DSharpPlus.Interactivity nuget installed.
Hope this helps, it helped me!